# What is "easy choice" in swimming program

Tags: terminology, swimming

While reading a swimming program I've met the following

> 4 x 25m Freestyle fast on 1 minute, 100m easy choice, 4 x 25m Not
>   Freestyle on 1 minute, 100m easy choice

What does "easy choice" mean here? Is this freestyle without speedup or is this breast swimming (i.e. choose some easy swimming style?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Easy choice" is a stroke of your choosing at an easy pace.  The rhythm of the program is hard/easy/hard/easy but only the first hard is with a specific stroke.

Answer (score 1):

I would expand on this a bit. "easy choice" does mean - swim whatever you want and slowly. However, the most important part of the "easy choice" is that it serves as recovery time and should get your rested again for the next hard set. So in other words, you should swim as slow as possible to get your heart rate back to a resting state.